# Dual Monitor Problem with Radeon HD 7570

Tags: drivers, graphics, ati, multiple-monitors

I am having dual monitor troubles. I have a monitor connected to my onboard Intel graphics card and a monitor connected to my Radeon HD 7570 graphics card. At the moment I have it set-up so that I am using the fglrx proprietary graphics driver. This causes only the monitor connected to my Radeon graphics card to display while the other monitor does not display anything (even though I can see both VGA devices in the terminal).

For some reason when I try to change the device driver to the AMD/ATI xserver-xorg-video-ati driver and reboot I get the message "The system is running in low-graphics mode". From there I cannot access Unity at all until I revert the video settings back to when I previously was working.

I can get the onboard monitor to work when I have a "manually installed driver" but then the other monitor no longer works. Anybody have any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Many motherboards will automatically turn off on-board video whenever there is a card present. 
Sometimes there is a way to override in the BIOS but usually not.

Does the 7570 not support two displays already?

Comment: I am not sure if that is the problem since I can access both monitors during the ubuntu 14.04 installation.

Comment: OK, well I still think it is something to do with the on-board and the card fighting.  If your card supports two displays (which I am pretty sure it does), why use the on-board?

Comment: Unfortunately I am unable to purchase an HDMI monitor at the moment and the video card only has an HDMI and DVI port.

Comment: You can get HDMI to dvi adapters readily and they are not too expensive.